# SQL Procedure Removing System Privledges

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that will remove system privileges from a certain user. When I compile my code I get "compilation errors"

```
create or replace procedure deactivate_user 
(
p_username in varchar2
)
as
l_username varchar2(30):=upper(p_username);
cnmd varchar2(50);
begin
    for rec (select privilege, admin_option from dba_sys_privs
            where grantee = l_username) loop
            cnmd := 'REVOKE '||rec.privilege||' from '||l_username;
execute immediate cnmd;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: It looks like Oracle PL/SQL to me

Comment: What do the errors say?

Comment: If you get a message like 'procedure created with compilation errors', use the [`show errors` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm#sthref2270) to get the actual error text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `IN` in the `FOR` statement; it should be:

```
FOR rec IN (SELECT privilege, admin_option FROM dba_sys_privs
            WHERE grantee = l_username) LOOP
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#CIHCGJAD

Comment: thanks. That got it to create the procedure but when I "exec deactivated_user" I get an error SQL> exec deactivate_user;
BEGIN deactivate_user; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DEACTIVATE_USER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @user2062656 - your procedure had a `p_username` parameter, but you haven't supplied an argument in your call. It should be `exec deactivate_user('USERNAME')`.